# Requesting data from Google Cloud ML Engine using the REST API in Scala

Tags: scala, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I want to retrieve information from a deployed ML-engine model using Scala code.

For example, how would the code look in order to achieve the REST-request for the "getConfig" method stated in this link: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call into the Java libraries from Scala. [This page](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict) has a code example of how to make a prediction request in Java (source code [direct link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/mlengine/online-prediction/src/main/java/OnlinePredictionSample.java)). It requires only a few modifications to use other methods. For instance, to call `getConfig`, you would make the following change:

```
RestMethod method = api.getResources().get("projects").getMethods().get("getConfig");
```

Hopefully this translates easily to Scala.